# Welcome file list not working

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

I have a web app which when run should open http://localhost:8084/info/user/user_login.jsp. I have given in my web.xml

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/user/user_login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But when running the app it opens as http://localhost:8084/info which is not able to obtain the css,jquery and image files.And I have to manually type /user/user_login.jsp after info to go to the right page.

My jsp is in 
info-->user(Folder)-->user_login.jsp
How Can I correct this

Comment: So to be clear, it takes you to the user_login.jsp page, but it doesn't load any of its css, script files, or page resources?

Comment: some more code will help

Comment: Could you please elaborate the requirement a bit for n add some more code for better understanding. ?

Comment: Create index.html which redirects to user_login.jsp

`<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=user/user_login.jsp">
 </head>
</html>`

Comment: @Neil-Yes it loads the page but I find all the resources on that page empty.(i.e)If i click the src="" link in by viewing page by source its empty,but to get each time I have to type /user/user_login.jsp in url to load with images and all

Comment: @DatoMumladze is that a right way to do? Are you sure?

Comment: @RajaDhasan Yes I use index.html in my projects

Comment: @DatoMumladze It worked Thanks

Comment: Alternatively you could make script/image paths absolute (with respect to request.getContextPath()) on your user_login.jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Place the user_login.jsp in following folder

> WebContent/user/user_login.jsp

and change in web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>user/user_login.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
```